# if then else statement inside a loop with variable files name sample

Tags: linux, bash

What am I doing wrong with this sample code?

```
for HOSTNAME in $(cat hostnames.txt)
do
        file ="/path/$HOSTNAME.crt"
        if [[-e "$file"]]
        then
                echo "file exist"
        else
                echo "file dose NOT Exist"
        fi
done
```

ERROR:

```
=/path/ad.tc.crt: cannot open ‘=/path/ad.tc.crt’ (No such file or directory)
./certs_check.sh: line 15: [[-e: command not found
file dose NOT Exist
=/path/cpscom.ds.crt: cannot open `=/path/cpscom.ds.crt' (No such file or directory)
./certs_check.sh: line 15: [[-e: command not found
file dose NOT Exist
```

The first file `/path/ad.tc.crt` exists so it should print "file does exist".

Comment: Square brackets must have spaces around them. See the linked question. [Shell Check](https://shellcheck.net) is good at diagnosing errors like this when bash's diagnostics don't suffice.

Comment: Also, you can't have a space before the `=` in an assignment. Spaces are important delimiters in shell syntax, so don't add or remove them unless you specifically know it's safe to.